# How to show bg color in fadeIn effect and remove style properties using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i want to change background color on hover function but i want to show in slow motion. Also i am adding some CSS Property on hover and want to remove and hover out. But my function does not work according to my requirment.

```
$(function (){

      $('.box').hover(function (){

          $('body').css({'background-color':'black'})

          $(this).css('-moz-transition', 'opacity .3s')
          $(this).css('-webkit-transition', 'opacity .3s')
          $(this).css('-o-transition', 'opacity .3s')
          $(this).css('-ms-transition', 'opacity .3s')

          }, function () {

              $('body').css({'background-color':'black'})

              $(this).remove('-moz-transition','none')

              })


      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the function just yet, but your hover function has some errors. get rid of the:

```
  $(this).css('-moz-transition', 'opacity .3s')
  $(this).css('-webkit-transition', 'opacity .3s')
  $(this).css('-o-transition', 'opacity .3s')
  $(this).css('-ms-transition', 'opacity .3s')
```

They shouldn't be assigned that way. Instead assign those attributes in your css for `.box`.

When you add the transition attributes get rid of opacity and add `-duration` to the end of `transition` so the final addition would look something like this: `-moz-transition-duration: 3s`

Are you wanting to change the document `body` `background-color` property, or the `.box background-color` property on hover? I am slightly confused.

If the change is on the body background here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5GpK/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Colour transitions can be done with Jquery UI. [Here's the demo.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)